# Is there a simple way to implement read and write privileges in active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'd like to create two separate admin logins for my active admin page on my Rails app.  One login should have read/write access, and the other should only have read access.  Is there a simple way to implement this in active admin?

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way I could think of, if you have just two admin logins, would be to use the activeadmin [authorization adapters](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html)

So you could try something like
(note this is a really simple example and hasn't been tested, check out the documentation for much better and cleaner examples and I apologize ahead of time if there are any errors!)

```
# app/models/only_admins_authorization.rb
class OnlyAdmins < ActiveAdmin::AuthorizationAdapter

  def authorized?(action, subject = nil)

    # Only let loginA create, update and delete
    if action == :update || action == :destroy || action == :create
      user.username == 'loginA' # check to see if current_user is loginA

    # If it's just read, let loginA or login B do it
    else
      user.username == 'loginA' || user.username == 'loginB' # check to see if current_user is loginA or loginB
    end

  end

end
```

and then in your view you could use `#authorized?` like

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do

  index do
    column :title
    column "" do |post|
      if authorized?(:update)
        link_to("Edit", admin_post_path(post))
      end
    end

  end

end
```

But if your app will have more than two logins as admins and could possibly grow, you might want to look into using the [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem and create roles for your users, and I believe activeadmin [authorization adapters plays nicely with cancan](http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#using_the_cancan_adapter)

I hope this helps